# Detecting repeating pattern in image

Tags: image, repeat, template-matching

Is it possible to detect pattern which is repeating in image? I have tried EmguCV and AForge's template matching. But that requires a template image to be provided. I want to identify the repeating template itself in the image.

Comment: Yes, try my [Python script](http://coding-experiments.blogspot.com/2009/03/detecting-copy-move-forgery-in-images.html) But I'll not comment much on this because I've done this code a long time ago